# How to play Audio file at specific time?

Tags: python, audio

I have a video which I am processing, frame by frame, and I would like based on the result of  frame processing to add multiple (short) audio file to it.

For example, let's say I have a program for **SQUAT COUNTING**, and every time I detect a **successful** or **unsuccessful** squat, I want to add a specific sound.

How would I do that, which libraries to use? I am using OpenCV for iterating through video frames, so the code looks something like this:

```
while(True):
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    try:
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out_frame, curr_proper_squat_num, curr_improper_squat_num = process_frame.process(frame, pose)
        if curr_proper_squat_num != prev_proper_squat_num:
            prev_proper_squat_num = curr_proper_squat_num
            # APPEND AUDIO STARTING FROM THIS FRAME
                
        elif curr_improper_squat_num != prev_improper_squat_num:
            prev_improper_squat_num = curr_improper_squat_num
            # APPEND AUDIO STARTING FROM THIS FRAME
            
        out_frame = cv2.cvtColor(out_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    except Exception as err:
        break
```

Which libraries would I use to append audio when I detect the frame from which I need audio to play?

Thanks!

Comment: you seem to be asking for recommendations of libraries that let you play audio. is that right? -- you made no attempt to _write_ any media files, so I'll assume that you want to play audio as the script executes.

Comment: I want to write an output composite of audio and video, but I am not even sure from where to start, or with which library to attempt to do it. I am looking into FFMPEG now

Comment: PyAV, if you want full control over ffmpeg, from Python. all the other "ffmpeg for python" "libraries" are toys, trying to emulate ffmpeg command line (transcoding) tasks. -- opencv is supposed to have some audio support, at least for reading. it's undocumented. I don't know if there is support for writing audio. either way, no docs for now.